# How to calculate stats for one column against another column in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the columns 'age' (int) and 'gender' which is a factor.

How would I calculate for each gender (male and female) separately, the median, mean, quantile (for probs=0.25) and quantile (for probs=0.75) for the age column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Age ~ Gender, data, summary)
  Gender Age.Min. Age.1st Qu. Age.Median Age.Mean Age.3rd Qu. Age.Max.
1 Female 21.00000    32.00000   43.00000 50.55556    69.00000 97.00000
2   Male  3.00000    26.00000   70.00000 55.72727    78.50000 95.00000
```

If you don't like the `summary` function, there are many other options.

Sample Data:

```
data <- data.frame( Age = sample(1:100,20, replace = TRUE), Gender = sample(factor(c("Female","Male")),20, replace = TRUE))
```